# gcd(a,b,100) = 1

Tags: number-theory

Find (a,b) ordered sets of positive integers such that gcd(a,b,100) is 1. a,b both are less than 100.

here's what i did. 100 = 2*5*5*2, so eliminate all the multiples of 5 and 2. gcd(a, gcd(b, 100) = gcd(a,b,100). both a and b cannot be multiples of 5 or 2, implies b has to chosen from 490 numbers while a could be chosen from the number of primes less than 100. so the total count should be 490*(no_primes_less_than 100) - 2(no_primes_less_than 100). but it doesn't work the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There are $99^2$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers with $1\le a\le 99$, $1\le b\le 99$.

Now let's count the **bad** pairs $(a,b)$, the pairs for which $\gcd(a,b,100)\gt 1$.

These are the pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ both between $1$ and $99$ such that $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $2$, and the pairs $(a,b)$ in the same interval such that $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $5$.

(i) How many pairs are there with $a$ and $b$ both divisible by $2$?

(ii) Repeat with divisible by $5$.

If we add together the answers to (i) and (ii), we will have double-counted the pairs where $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $10$.

Now put things together.